# Export data as JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to export data as a json file in a stored procedure. It is possible to export the data as a XML file, but I want to know how can I do the same thing using JSON?

Comment: Hint: [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar as to export into XML, in your query you should use:

```
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

More information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15